# Keyboard & touchpad and mouse

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, mouse

I use a Macbook pro 16 I tried to install Elementary OS and I haven’t been able to 1 my keyboard did not work 2 my toucpad or mouse did either work. Is there a fix for that soon. I do not have a secondary computer so I hope there will come a fix for all that.

Comment: no answer or solution at all I been searching on the net about it. But there was  nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

This may be able to help you: [Keyboard and touchpad are not working.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310324)

You will have to manually install some drivers and patches.